# App crashes after upgrade to big sur in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Today I had this great idea to update android studio, Xcode, and my mac. I am now running Xcode 12.2 and Android studio 4.1.1 on a Big Sur 11.0.1.

My flutter app, of course, got broken by this update however I managed to fix all the issues which were visible to me. Now I am able to run my app on a simulator and real devices. My problem is that if I run the app on a real iPhone (ios ) and stop the app, then if I tap on the app on my iPhone the app crashes. If I do the same in the simulator the app is launching properly...

Does anyone know if this is the intended behavior or not?

Thanks

Comment: is your physical device up to date ?

Comment: Yes I have iOS 14.2

Comment: I am thinking i might have an issue with certificates... but not sure where to look. any idea?